# Regex - find all string function arguments in file

Tags: java, regex, plsql

I need a regex which will extract all the string function arguments in a given text file. It is a PL/SQL script file so the `''` escapes a `'` in strings.

An example:

```
foo('My foo arg! Something.') --> 'My foo arg! Something.'
bar('My bar arg', number) --> 'My bar arg'

// note the spaces
foo(   'My foo arg') --> 'My foo argument'
bar(   'My bar arg', number) --> 'My bar arg'

foo(''My escaped string'') --> ''My escaped string''
bar(''My escaped string'', number) --> ''My escaped string''
```

I wrote a simple pattern but it doesn't work as expected:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*\\([\\s]*((([']{1,2})?))(([\\w\\W&&[^']&&]*)*((([']{2})?))*)*'",
                Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
```

#### EDIT

Valid examples are:

```
-- expected: 'My foo arg! Something.'
BEGIN
    foo('My foo arg! Something.');
END; 

-- expected: ''My foo arg! Something.'' or 'My foo arg! Something.'
DECLARE
 v_sql VARCHAR(4000) := 'SELECT foo(''My foo arg! Something.'') FROM sys.dual';
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
END;
```

Comment: Are you sure you can have `foo(''My escaped string'')`? Not `foo('''My escaped string''')`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure...

Comment: But you say `''` means a literal `'` inside a `'`-quoted substring. Isn't `foo(''My escaped string'')`  an example of wrong syntax?

Comment: Maybe to make it clear, the method foo is part of a string: `'SELECT foo(''My escaped string'') FROM sys.DUAL'`.

Comment: But then `'SELECT foo('My foo arg! Something.') FROM sys.dual'` would be invalid? How you have described it, both examples cannot be correct.

Comment: Edited.........

Answer (score 0):

It seems maybe I'm missing something, but this seems to work:

`'{1,2}[^']+'{1,2}`

In english, this reads:

- `'{1,2}` - find 1 or 2 single quotes
- `[^']+` - find 1 or more characters that aren't a single quote
- `'{1,2}` - find 1 or 2 single quotes

See it in action on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PMsizg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classic problem of "find all quoted strings and honour escaped quotation marks". The canonical answer here is:

```
'(?:''|[^'])*'
```

It matches the opening quote and then any number of escaped (doubled) quotes or non-quotes, terminated by the closing quote.

Demo at https://regexr.com/564c3